# Prestashop no responsive theme to responsive

Tags: prestashop-1.5

Can anybody tell me how i will change a prestashop theme from non responsive to responsive? where i will place media css code?

```
/* iPads (portrait) ----------- */
@media only screen and (min-width : 768px) and (max-width : 1024px) and (orientation : portrait) {
/* Styles */
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the best solution for you is download responsive PrestaShop theme and clone whatever you need

This link for paid themes

http://themeforest.net/category/ecommerce/prestashop

if you want free one you can download this

http://www.templatemonster.com/free-responsive-prestashop-theme.html

also you can use this tool

http://presta-theme-maker.com/

I hope that will help you